# Unable to execute a "nonexistent" file

Tags: command-line, executable

[image: Screenshot...]

If you can't see the screenshot, I'm connected to my raspberry pi running Ubuntu Server. I followed the instructions and put the `cloudflared` file in `/usr/local/bin`. As I try to execute it from my home directory, it says the executable in `/usr/local/bin` does not exist!

However, it clearly knows the file exists because it sees the file in that directory. Otherwise, it would just say "command not found." Yes, I have the correct architecture and yes, I added the executable permission. I can't run it as ubuntu or root.

Need I say more?

Comment: What does `ldd /usr/local/bin/cloudflared` say?

Comment: "not a dynamic executable"

Comment: I did... `sudo chmod +X cloudflared` run in its directory adds it.

Comment: OK so what does `file -L /usr/local/bin/cloudflared` say?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/cloudflared: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, Go BuildID=2OYWqsn6HwlKAC9qDgrU/ceFGNZMLLSFwm6_q8BiY/HvwTvmBiT1-ZFFS4QJxb/B0H2enVrcAyr4U2z1r8t, BuildID[sha1]=8caaf62326479b2e146988bc7eab087f6cf43736, not stripped`

Comment: Apparently you don't have the ARM loader on your system, and the ldd script will not handle that gracefully, simply saying not a dynamic executable. See launchpad bug 1616609

Comment: And I fix this by adding the loader? I'd assume I'd need an update or to install a loalder package...

Answer (score 0):

From your "file" output, the interpreter is /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3

```
apt-file search /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
```

will give you the package
libc6-armhf-cross, so install that, but that's from my x64 system.
Look at ldd itself, and see what the RTLDLIST= line looks like, and pick out the loader you need (maybe just /lib/ld-linux.so.3).

Comment: did you mean `apt-file`?

Comment: I still get the same issue with ldd and when executing it anywhere